# Get all multiple listbox values

Tags: php, javascript

I have a multiple selection listbox in which I insert items using javascript. At a certain point I need to get the values of all entries (both selected and unselected).
I'm currently using this code:

```
<form method="post" action="?page=test" name="something">
<select name="thelist[]" id="selOriginalWindow" size="5" multiple="multiple">
</select>
<input type="button" value="Добави" onclick="openInNewWindow();" />
<input type="submit" value="Get" />
</form>

    <?
if ($_GET['page']=="test") {
    $thelist=$_POST['thelist'];
    var_dump($thelist);
}   
    ?>
```

Javascript inserts the values, but PHP only gets the selected items' value. How do I get the value of all of the items in that listbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This did the trick:

```
function selectAll(selectBox,selectAll) {
    if (typeof selectBox == "string") {
        selectBox = document.getElementById(selectBox);
    }
    if (selectBox.type == "select-multiple") {
        for (var i = 0; i < selectBox.options.length; i++) {
            selectBox.options[i].selected = selectAll;
        }
    }
}
</script>
<form method="post" action="?page=test" name="something">
<select name="thelist[]" id="selOriginalWindow" size="5" multiple="multiple">
</select>
<input type="button" value="Добави" onclick="openInNewWindow();" />
<input type="submit" value="Get" onclick="selectAll('selOriginalWindow',true)" />
</form>

    <?
if ($_GET['page']=="test") {
    $thelist=$_POST['thelist'];
    var_dump($thelist);
}   
    ?>
```

Comment: @DreamWave but how can you now distinguish between what the user selected and what the code selected? What's the point in drop down, if you auto select everything??

Comment: The idea is that the listbox is empty at the beginning. The user clicks on a button that opens a new window where he selects in three different dropdowns. The result is then formatted and inserted in the first window as a formatted value and text. The user made his choice, then I need all of the entries.
In the end this will be a transport system - I need this so the user can select a country,an area and a city.. but since there are a lot of combinations between them - this is the way I decided it should be like. Sorry if I didnt explain well enough in my post.

Comment: @DreamWave so why drop down? It's bit confusing for the user that he can select items but it has no meaning. Put it as pure text instead..

Comment: @Shadow Wizard its a multiple selection listbox, not a dropdown

Comment: @DreamWave sorry, my point is: why let user select items when this selection has no meaning?

Comment: The selection has no meaning but I use the listbox to move items up and down after they've been entered.

Answer (score 1):

The post variable will only contain those values you select, therefore if you want to use the same methodology to send ALL values you will need to add an additional field to your form which includes ALL the values. You can then read all values from this.

One way would be to use `<input ='hidden' value='arrayofallvalues' name='allvalues'/>`

So you could have the following:

```
<?
$select_values=array('value1', 'value2','value3');
?>

<form method="post" action="?page=test" name="something">
<select name="thelist[]" id="selOriginalWindow" size="5" multiple="multiple">
<?
for ( $i= 0; $i< count($select_values); $i++) {
    echo "<option value=".$select_values[$i].">".$select_values[$i]."</option>";
}

?>
</select>
<input ='hidden' value='".implode(",",$select_values)."' name='allvalues'/>
<input type="button" value="Добави" onclick="openInNewWindow();" />
<input type="submit" value="Get" />

</form>

    <?
if ($_GET['page']=="test") {
    $thelist=$_POST['thelist'];
    $all_select_values=explode(",",$_POST['allvalues']);
    var_dump($thelist);
}   
    ?>
```

What this will do is mean that every time the form submits, you can use explode() to create an array of the available values for the selct box.

Comment: Yes, I usually use this code but this time I cannot. The values that are entered in the selectbox are unique and unknown by php - The user selects them and inserts them trough javascript. That's why the options part is missing in my code-options are dynamically inserted. Maybe I should insert a javascript that will select all of the values upon clicking the submit button ?