# PHP I want to demand my Array at my will

Tags: php, arrays, function

First off, I am a PHP NOOB.
I am currently trying to develop a PHP page that is suppose to calculate a monthly budget for you and I am having problem with one section of it.

I am having problem with my food variables. 
I can't give you the syntax I have for the "foodPerMonth" array because I simply don't know how to write it. Everything I've written so far is wrong.

Anyhow. This is how I want it to work.

I have my html form. I'm making it shorter just for the food part. 
You are suppose to type in how many i.e "Adult Woman" you want in your budget.
And I will have a variable for each of those that will contain the cost per month for each person.

```
<form action="function.php" method="post">
<label>Adult Woman: </label><input type="text" name="foodPerMonth[]" /><br />
<label>Adult Man: </label><input type="text" name="foodPerMonth[]" /><br />
<label>Juvenile Girl: </label><input type="text" name="foodPerMonth[]" /><br />
<label>Juvenile Boy: </label><input type="text" name="foodPerMonth[]" /><br />
<label>Child Girl: </label><input type="text" name="foodPerMonth[]" /><br />
<label>Child Boy: </label><input type="text" name="foodPerMonth[]" /><br />
<label>Baby Girl: </label><input type="text" name="foodPerMonth[]" /><br />
<label>Baby Boy: </label><input type="text" name="foodPerMonth[]" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

What I want to know is how do I type this kind of array that will go with the form and etc.

I would also appreciate if someone could thorougly explain how arrays and keys work and how they are used and what they are used for. Doesn't matter how much I read the fact in the manual. It wont stuck.

Thank you in advance for answering, all help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Don't use php.net to learn how to code. Use it for a resource. Search Google for php tutorials, there are a TON available.

Comment: Why an array?  This isn't the correct plan for an array really.  That `foodPerMonth[]` array syntax is primarily meant for multi-select list boxes.  Where you have many items, in a list box, and you want the array to be populated. by selecting items from the list.  Also a set of checkbox, might be useful with that syntax.

Comment: Examples: Checkboxes http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14026361/php-multiple-checkbox-array - Multi-select list box. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4183015/get-all-multiple-listbox-values

Comment: It's suppose to be checkboxes Zoredache. That's why I have foodPerMonth[]

And Relentless, I've searched all around to try to find the way I wan't to do this script. I just can't find it. I keep getting directed to stackoverflow. 

Btw why vote down the question? I mean, it's not a stupid question or anything.

Comment: That's a fine answer Zoredache, but how does the PHP code look like if I would use that multiple checkbox?

Comment: @ChristofferZebranVik You could set it up like so `foreach($_POST["foodPerMonth"]   as  $value)  { $foodPerMonth  .=  "$value\n";}` that will echo each value for your checkboxes without making any changes to your present code.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want:

```
<label>Adult Woman: <input type="text" name="foodPerMonth[adultwoman]" /></label><br />
<label>Adult Man: <input type="text" name="foodPerMonth[adultman]" /></label><br />
```

[note: also wrap the labels around the inputs]

Which will be accessible via:

```
$_POST['foodPerMonth']['adultman'];
$_POST['foodPerMonth']['adultwomman'];
```

Just the blank `foodPerMonth[]` syntax crams everything into a numbered array which skips any fields left blank making the numbering unreliable.

Comment: Ahh of course! Thank you that's genius! :D

How can I echo those ?

Comment: Isn't it Implode and explode I should use or perhaps a foreach loop?

Comment: `foreach( $_POST['foorPerMonth'] as $key => $value ) { echo "$key: $value<br/>"; }` will get you started.

Comment: @Sammitch If that's not a direct copy of my [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18730260/php-i-want-to-demand-my-array-at-my-will#comment27602970_18730260), I don't know what is. So don't take the credit for it. All you did was change `\n` for `<br />`

Comment: That's not a direct copy of your comment. They are much alike but very very different. Thanks to both of you.

Comment: @ChristofferZebranVik I wasn't referring to his answer but his comment above, as per my original comment under your question.

Comment: @Fred-ii- your comment doesn't refer to an associative array, and will be unreliable if a field is left blank. But aside from that yeah I guess we both have a firm grasp of basic loop syntax. :I