# Echo unselected listbox values from html to php

Tags: php, html, jquery, listbox

Let me start this off by saying I'm a total newbie with html, jquery, and php programming.  I'm the only one in my office with any programming experience (python, matlab, R) and have been tasked with creating a webpage to search a database.  The web interface looks very similar to what is available on http://trdb.wcasfmra.org/, but with a "Submit" button.  Up to this point I've been able to echo information from the textboxes and checkboxes (to make sure I can get the values I need) but I'm having a ton of problems with the listboxes.  When the user selects "By County" they are able to drag and drop a county from one listbox to the other.  My question is this: how do I get the list of counties in the Selected listbox to echo out? The only way I can get it to work now is by having them highlighted, which kind of defeats the purpose of having a list of potential counties and selected counties.  Below is some of my own code I pasted in here.

This is the Counties listbox:

```
<select style="width: 140px;height: 273px" multiple="multiple" id='avail_counties'>
<option value="Adams">Adams</option>
<option value="Barron">Barron</option>
...</select>
```

This is the Selected listbox:

```
<select style="width: 140px;height: 273px" multiple="multiple" id='select_counties' name="selectCounties[]">
</select>
```

I've combed over the net for the last two days and have tried a lot of different things but don't know enough of the syntax to get it straightened out.  I'm sure this is a simple thing for those of you who do this for a career but it's been difficult for me.  I don't necessarily understand what code i should use and where it should go.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  If you need additional information from me please let me know and I'll respond ASAP.  My html file is called DatabaseSearch.html and the php script is called SearchTest.php (if it helps at all).

Comment: That's the thing about multi-select, it will only send the selected options, if any. If you're having to pre-select everything manually, you can add an `onsumbit` event when the submit button is clicked, so that the javascript can select everything before hand. If this is could be a potential idea, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4183242/7644018).